# VSCode - Can I breakpoint on client javascript

Tags: visual-studio-code

This may be a stupid question, but is it possible on VS Code to set a breakpoint on a client side javascript file and have it pause while debugging?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can break in the client itself.

- On Chrome: Press F12(windows) or open the developer tools, then go to
  the sources tab and add the breakpoints.
- Safari: Enable dev tools in
  options.  The rest of it is the same as chrome
- Firefox: Enable javascript console

[image: Breakpoint demonstrated in chrome. Just click on the line number.]

Comment: Thanks! Yeah I knew about that, but I was curious if that was built in to VS Code.

Comment: Not currently, but you can vote for it at https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/293070-visual-studio-code

Comment: Thanks Alex! I went ahead and added my vote for that feature!

Answer (score 1):

This may not be what you're wanting. But, you can simply add a debugger line in your code, and the browser will break on that line.

```
// some code here
debugger
// some more code here
```

Just make sure that your jshint alerts you to "forgotten" debugger statements.